# AWS - create a subdomain, too much information on website

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, dns, routes

I'm creating 2 subdomains for 1 domain. They are web.example.com and api.example.com form example.com domain.
I read the official website. Have to say it is documented into every detail. But too much reading makes me confused.

I have example.com registered and I am going to put it as a site in my IIS. I know the public IP address of my server (an EC2 instance) which is running IIS. What will be the IP address for my example.com? The same as my server's public IP address?

Also, do I need a new IP address for my subdomain api. and web.? Or it is just routing configuration and I can use my server's public IP address.

Sorry, my networking knowledge isn't sufficient.

Just to ask does creating record set include 3 main steps?
1 - creating hosted zone
2 - creating record set (what will be the type in my case? IPv4 or CNAME?)
3 - updating name server

Comment: You can host many sites on the same IIS. Just specify "host name" while creating the website, i.e. api.example.com and www.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can host as many sites on IIS as you want, you only need to specify the host name for each site such as api.example.com and web.example.com. They can both have the same IP address and when you configure the DNS you create a new A record for each one and add the same IP address, which is the public IP of your EC2 instance as the IP address.

Secondly while it is good practice to add an A record to your zone apex (which is example.com in this example) it is not absolutely required.